# Angular 2 Search pipe filter from object containing another object in it?

Tags: angular, search, angular-filters, angular-pipe

I want to implement search on objects contains object in it.
I want to filter Property_id parameters using angular search filter. how i can apply search filters only on "property_id" object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipe as follows,

```
@Pipe({name: 'filterByPropertyId'})
export class FilterByPropertyId implements PipeTransform {

    transform(yourList: yourObject[], property_id: string): any[] {
        if (yourList) {
            return yourList.filter((yourList: yourObject) => list.property_id === property_id);
        }
    }
}
```

and in the component level

```
  <div *ngFor="let r of yourList| FilterByPropertyId:propertyId">

  </div>
```